# Read a file line by line -> search for each line in another text document, if match, output to another text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script that takes two parameters.

```
ls $1 > $1.txt
ls $2 > $2.txt
```

I now have a.txt ($1 is directory 'a', $2 is directory 'b') and b.txt each with their contents listed inside them. What I want to do is search line by line in a.txt and see if there is a match in b.txt.

If I have these files in a.txt:

```
file1 -> search for file1 in b.txt, if match, output to a_match.txt
file2 -> search for file2 in b.txt, if match, output to a_match.txt
file3 -> search for file3 in b.txt, if match, output to a_match.txt
```

Vice versa for b.txt. How would I do this? Also, not looking for alternative methods to doing this, there are soooo many other ways to check differences amongst directories, but this is the only acceptable way for my assignment :(

Comment: Does the output need to be in a particular format?

Comment: Yes it does, but that is what I'm not having trouble with, it's just the reading and manipulation of files that I can't wrap around my head. Once I have the two final files of the differences in a and b, I know how to return them to console in the format that I want, aka ls -l.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is clearly homework so I'm not going to give you a full solution.  Here's the outline

```
while "there are lines left in the file, read a line" do
     grep "the line" "the file"
done
```

the key for getting lines is the `read` command.  Do `help read` in bash for details.

**Update**

Okay, so let's look a little more closely.  Start the script with

Let's call the script a.bash.  You'll want to run it as

```
 $ a.bash b.txt < a.txt > a_match.txt
```

`a.bash` is a script that reads line from a.txt, searches in `b.txt` and sends output to STDOUT which you then direct into your file a_match.txt .

Start the script witha "shebang line'.  Usually it's

```
 #!/usr/bin/bash --
```

or something similar.

The `read` primitive simply reads a line into a variable, and by default reads into a variable named REPLY.  So "there are lines left in the file, read a line" is simply

```
 while read
```

The name of the file to search in will be in the special shell variable $1, representing the first argument.  Since the other names are used in redirection, they don't appear as arguments at all.

Now, the command *grep(1)* searches a file for a string and put's the line on which the string occurs onto STDOUT.  So all we need for the search is

```
 grep $REPLY b.txt
```

(Read the man page for [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep).)

Since *grep(1)* puts the output on STDOUT anyway, it'll go out and be redirected into `a_matches.txt`.  That's your "grep the line in the file" line.

Now just fit that all together.

Quiz:

1. Why is it `$REPLY`?
2. How would you change the script so you could call it as:

   $ a.bash a.txt b.txt a_matches.txt

Comment: I don't even know where to begin, this is where I was at when I started, thanks I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick solution that I think meets your requirements:

```
fgrep -x -f b.txt a.txt > a_match.txt
```

Comment: Ah I understand it now, thanks. How would the opposite be done, if for example I wanted to list files that were not mutual?

Comment: Wow I didn't even know about the 'man' command, this is wonderful. Thanks.

Comment: Got it: `fgrep -f -v a.txt b.txt` yields the difference, now to put it into a loop!

Answer (score 0):

This could help you just go through the tutorial and it bests meet your requirements.Again there is not just one way to read a file line by line and some are faster than others and some are more intuitive than others.

http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/18009-12-ways-parse-file.html

Comment: Cannot employ anything that uses functions, we've not learnt that.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I would use:

```
diff dir1/ dir2/
```

or

```
diff "$1" "$2"
```

Comment: Dennis, that doesn't even faintly do what the assignment says.

Comment: @CharlieMartin: Sure it does. The output might need to be manipulated to look a certain way, though.

Comment: I lol'd, I used this way, as well as comm -23 <(____) <(____) and other methods to accomplish, none of which we are allowed to use due to this course being extremely beginner.

Comment: it just doesn't: look at the assignment: write a script that reads line by line and writes the matched lines to a file.  Yes, diff compares lines -- but the output includes the lines from both, your solution doesn't do anything to filter out the unmatched lines, and the results aren't going into a file. It delivers the wrong output to the wrong place using the wrong method.  Other than that it's fine, I guess.